# Why characters UTF-8 encoded are ISO-8859-1 encoded when written in an external file

Tags: pdftex, unicode, input-encodings, auxiliary-files

For an UTF-8 encoded file as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\newwrite\outtmp
\immediate\openout\outtmp=out.tmp
%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\foo}{Résumé}
\foo
\immediate\write\outtmp{\foo}%
\end{document}
```

the `out.tmp` output file is ISO-8859-1 encoded. Why:

- not UTF-8?
- ISO-8859-1 and not something else?

Comment: Since you've told LaTeX that the input is utf8, it's able to map it to its internal representation, then output it in whatever encoding is applicable for output. (Why that is Latin-1 and how to change it, I couldn't say).

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but when you exchange `inputenc` with `luainputenc` and translate it with lualatex, then the out.tmp is UTF8-encoded.

Comment: @alexis Sorry I don't understand "whatever encoding is applicable for output".

Comment: You are using pdfTeX for this? If so, remember that it's an 8-bit program.

Comment: @knut Indeed, and it works also with XeLaTeX when replacing `inputenc` and `fontenc` by `fontspec`.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes: I'm running `pdflatex`. I guess you meant it is *not* an 8-bit program, don't you?

Comment: I meant that perhaps there are ways to change the encoding of the output. But default TeX is a 7- or 8-bit program, so it makes sense that whatever it reads, it stores and outputs in an 8-bit format (which ISO-8859-N is, but utf-8 is not). I'm speaking without knowing the real technical facts, but your odds of getting what you want would be better if you did _not_ tell TeX it's reading utf-8-- since then it would not know how to convert it, and just might keep it intact. (But the generated document would almost certainly be incorrect).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I meant exactly what I said: pdfTeX is 8-bit, and as alexis says an internal representation ('LICR') is used to handle UTF-8 characters which  are not single byte ones. Thus reading a UTF-8 file involves turning the two or more bytes that pdfTeX 'sees' into something that can be handled as a single char.

Comment: @alexis I learned something: I was sure utf-8 stores and outputs in an 8-bit format. And you're right, not telling TeX it's reading utf-8 does the trick.

Comment: Well, Joseph presumably meant that pdflatex is _restricted_ to 8-bit characters. You could say `utf-8` is an "8-bit format" in the sense that it uses all 8 bits of a byte (as opposed to ASCII, which is a 7-bit encoding because it never uses the high bit). But utf-8 needs multiple bytes per character (there's no way the thousands of characters of unicode could be mapped to the 256 8-bit values). Unicode is nominally 16-bit (though the "extended plane" goes higher), and utf-8 uses anywhere from 1 to three bytes (8 to 24 bits) to code one unicode character.

Comment: LaTeX doen't know anything about encodings on output to a file. It just writes whatever bytes you give it, subject to expansion of control sequences and active characters. That is the problem with `inputenc` for most encodings: some characters are made active to translate characters into latex notation. If that were not the case, it would happily write multibyte characters byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main point here is that the input file is not LaTeX but a mixture of LaTeX and plain TeX or rather TeX primitives that are not supported in LaTeX files (ok they appear inside packages and inside the kernel, but using them means one has to understand the (sometimes not properly documented limitations and the conventions to get around them).

So TeX is writing as if it is typesetting (given a certain font encoding (not file encoding)), @egreg described that perfectly in his answer.

LaTeX goes a long way to define an internal encoding that can be translated to various font  encodings or other encodings and if you would want to get utf-8 output you would need to switch first to to a "font" encoding that outputs utf-8, ie that translates stuff like `\'e` (which is an LICR = LaTeX Internal Character Encoding) to the two utf-8 bytes. Now that doesn't exist but technically it would be possible to set up properly.

The use of `\protected@write` is the LaTeX way to output stuff transparently on 7bit so that it can be read back in regardeless of the input encoding in force at that time

Answer (score 25):

### How does LaTeX implement UTF-8?

The Unicode character `é` is encoded as two byte in UTF-8, precisely `<C3><A9>` (I'll use throughout this to denote bytes, also when they are character tokens for TeX). When `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is loaded, the byte `<C3>` is made *active* and defined to look for the following byte, because `<C3>` in UTF-8 marks a two byte character.

So LaTeX gathers `<A9>` and forms the control sequence

```
\csname u8:\string<C3>\string<A9>\endcsname
```

which is defined to expand to

```
\IeC {\@tabacckludge 'e}
```

One can see it from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\show\csname u8:\string^^c3\string^^a9\endcsname
```

where `^^c3` is TeX's way to express what I denote by `<C3>`. On the terminal we get

```
> \u8:é=macro:
->\IeC {\@tabacckludge 'e}.
<recently read> \u8:é 

l.4 ...r\show\csname u8:\string?\string?\endcsname
```

(the `é` in the first line is because my terminal is set up for UTF-8).

### What does `\write` do?

The operation `\write` takes a first argument denoting the output stream and a braced second argument, which is *fully expanded* when the write operation is actually performed. So we need to know what `\IeC` and `\@tabacckludge` do.

Adding `\show\IeC` and `\makeatletter\show\@tabacckludge` to the above example shows, on the terminal, first

```
> \IeC=macro:
->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \@firstofone \else \noexpand \IeC \fi .
```

and then

```
> \@tabacckludge=macro:
#1->\expandafter \@changed@cmd \csname \string #1\endcsname \relax .
```

OK, we'd need also `\@changed@cmd`, but in essence it simply does the equivalent of `\'e`, since we're not in a `tabbing` environment.

In your case, `\protect` *is* `\@typeset@protect`, as it is normally; so when we do

```
\write\openout{é}
```

we first get

```
\IeC{\@tabacckludge 'e}
```

and, since the conditional is true, this becomes

```
\@firstofone{\@tabacckludge 'e}
```

which in turn becomes

```
\@tabacckludge 'e
```

and then

```
\'e
```

This one triggers a complex development, which eventually ends into

```
\char223
```

because of the declaration

```
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{T1}{e}{233}
```

in `t1enc.def` that has been loaded by saying `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Only now TeX actually writes something, precisely byte number 233 (in decimal), that is, byte `<E9>`.

It's not really a coincidence that `<E9>` in Latin-1 is exactly `é`, because the T1 encoding has many slots in common with Latin-1. Not all.

### How do we write UTF-8 with LaTeX (as opposed to (Xe|Lua)LaTeX)?

You don't want the expansion takes place:

```
\write\outtmp{\unexpanded{Résumé}}
```

or, without using `\unexpanded`,

```
\toks0={Résumé}
\write\outtmp{\the\toks0}
```

**Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\outtmp
\immediate\openout\outtmp=\jobname.tmp

\immediate\write\outtmp{Résumé}
\immediate\write\outtmp{\unexpanded{Résumé}}
\toks0={Résumé}
\immediate\write\outtmp{\the\toks0 }

\stop
```

The result of `less` from the written out file is

```
R<E9>sum<E9>
Résumé
Résumé
```

(always because the terminal is UTF-8). Without interpretation I get

```
R<E9>sum<E9>
R<C3><A9>sum<C3><A9>
R<C3><A9>sum<C3><A9>
```

So the first line is the wrong one, while the other two are as expected.

Hiding `Résumé` in a macro just makes things more difficult, because you *want* to expand it. So

```
\write\outtmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\foo}}
```

will do.

### What else?

If you use `\protected@write`, then things are different: with

```
\protected@write\outtmp{}{Résumé}
```

you get written

```
R\IeC {\'e}sum\IeC {\'e}
```

because in this case `\protect` is not `\@typeset@protect`, so the false branch is followed. The complex transformation of `\@tabacckludge 'e` ends up with `\'e` because of the same reason regarding `\protect`. This might be or not what you want. Surely that token list prints as “Résumé”.

Comment: This answer saved my day! `\write\outtmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\foo}}` is the solution to a recent problem I had. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm For an even better `tcolorbox`? :)

Comment: In this case: no. But I want to migrate my documents to UTF-8 and I wonder what more pitfalls are coming (?). Now, this one is closed thanks to your answer :-)