# nameref + fontenc causes umlauts in aux-File

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, font-encodings

I wrote a small new command that makes use of `\@currentlabelname` and `\nameref`. When I have Umlauts in the labelname (the argument of `\@currentlabelname`) everything works fine until I use the fontenc package. Then the umlauts are not correctly escaped/transformed into the .aux-File, which then causes an inputenc error.

Here is a minimal example. Run twice to get the error! Any ideas how to make this work with fontenc?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %causes Umlauts in -aux-file and therefore an inputenc-error on the second run
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\AP[1]{%
    \subsubsection*{#1}%
    \edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \AP{endgültig}
    \label{foo}
    \nameref{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Have you checked out the posting [Why characters UTF-8 encoded are ISO-8859-1 encoded when written in an external file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149062/5001)? Read, in particular, @egreg's posting. Your issue and the one reported in the other posting could be related.

Comment: Don't use this automation for labels: accented characters are not safe for a `\label`.

Comment: Related [What to consider when naming labels to prevent errors ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109443/15717)

Comment: Thanks for the linked threads, @egreg explained the issue very well. Still, it does not provide a solution for pdflatex, right? But, it led me to the conclusion that it should work with lualatex and yes, it does (replace fontenc and inputenc with fontspec of course). Is that the best solution or do I oversee something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve the issue by using `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\AP[1]{%
  \subsubsection*{#1}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\AP{endgültig}\label{foo}

\nameref{foo}

\end{document}
```